# How to create a multiple interface com class in C#

Tags: c#, interface, com

I want to create a COM class in C#, which implements two interfaces, like this.

```
[Guid("59F2009C-07ED-4459-AC60-7E8A85C445F1")]
public interface IA
{
    [DispId(1)] void MethodA();
}

[Guid("1E325582-E192-4C73-A214-1A633918ABDA")]
public interface IB
{
    [DispId(1)] void MethodB();
}
```

Then, I want to write a COM class like this.

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class MyCOM : IA, IB
{
    public void MethodA();

    public void MethodB();
}
```

Unfortunately, it just could be seen MethodA in MyCOM from VB, because IA is prior to IB. But I hope I can use both MethodA and MethodB in MyCOM of VB. Anybody can help me how to do?

Also, I have try like this:

```
public interface IA : IB {}

public class MyCOM : IA {}
```

The result is the same as above, i.e. MethodB was disappear in MyCOM.

Comment: Can you share the code which is trying to call `MethodB` ?

Comment: With VB you will have to create two variables like `Dim a As MyCOM` and `Dim b as IB` and then cast `Set b = a`. Then you will be able to do `b.MethodB`

Comment: Both methods will get the same `DispId` ("1"). Could that be the problem? Try to have unique numbers and see what happens.

Comment: It seems only one interface, could not be two, in a com object.